# array_diff on assoc array only showing the first result and not all

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a continuation from another question where I forgot to ask the full question.  Luck I did because I was about to ask the wrong question.  Ok I have the following two arrays

```
Array ( [idAsset] => 10000005 [AssetName] => HP ) 
Array ( [idAsset] => 10000006 [AssetName] => HP Server ) 
Array ( [idAsset] => 10000009 [AssetName] => HP Laptop ) 
Array ( [idAsset] => 10000010 [AssetName] => Office Printer ) 
Array ( [idAsset] => 10000023 [AssetName] => test ) 




Array ( [idAsset] => 10000023 [AssetName] => test )
```

I got these using the following code

```
  $firstArray = array();
   $secondArray = array();
    do{
    array_push($firstArray,$array1);
    }while($array1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($AssetUp));


do{
array_push($secondArray ,$array2);
 }while($array2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DocUp));

$array3 = array_diff_key($firstArray, $secondArray);
 print_r($array3);
```

However this leaves me with the following:

```
  Array ( 
  [2] => Array ( [idAsset] => 10000006 [AssetName] => HP Server ) 
  [3] => Array ( [idAsset] => 10000009 [AssetName] => HP Laptop ) 
  [4] => Array ( [idAsset] => 10000010 [AssetName] => Office Printer ) 
  [5] => Array ( [idAsset] => 10000023 [AssetName] => test ) )
```

It seems to be leaving out the first loop and also still including the test asset

I'm trying to be left with one array that does not include items found in both arrays.  For example from above the 10000023 test would be removed from both arrays leaving me with the first 4 rows from $firstArray  (this is why the first question would have been wrong)  I want only the differences not the similarities.

Comment: array_diff_assoc is not multi dimensional.

Comment: If you changed both arrays to use the `idAsset` as their first level key, you cann diff based on that key.

Comment: Hi @Tobe thanks for the answer.  Can you explain a little as I dont think I understand what you mean.  Currently the first thing i ask for from both queries is idAsset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming, your arrays are as follows:

```
$data = array( array( "idAsset" => 10000005, "AssetName" => "HP" ),
               array( "idAsset" => 10000006, "AssetName" => "HP Server" ),
               ... );
```

array_diff_assoc is not going to check any sub arrays. So in your case it will only compare your numeric indizes which isnt what you need.

A good idea might be to also use the `idAsset` you want to compare as the array key:

```
$data = array( "10000005" => array( "idAsset" => 10000005, "AssetName" => "HP" ),
               "10000006" => array( "idAsset" => 10000006, "AssetName" => "HP Server" ),
               ... );
```

If you now compare them via `array_diff_key`, it will return any differenced in key only. And since that's your criteria ... voilá

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-diff-key.php